# 'js runtime error expected object' (line20)or where $(document).ready starts

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <div id="header">
     <center><button type="button" onclick="JavaScript:prompt('so far sogood')">
  click</button></center>
  </div>

 <style type="text/css">                                 
#one{width:100%; height:100px;background-color:red;}
#two{width:100%; height:100px;background-color:green;}
#header{width:100%; height:100px;background-color:yellow;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(
{
$('.one').mouseenter(function()
{
$(this).fadeOut('slow'); 
});

$('.one').mouseleave(function()
    {
 $(this).fadeIn('fast');

}); 

});
</script>


 </head>
<body bgcolor="black">





<div id="one"><center>HELLO</center></div>
 <div id ="two">hello</div>
 </body>
```

it looks like my problem is where my jquery line starts right after `$(document)` takes places. apparently im not putting something right before this takes place. i am new to jquery and usually i use an external css page so different format takes places

Comment: If this is your whole script i do not see a reference to jquery.js - either a local version or the CDN version  included anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error : last parenthesis is missing after ready function declaration

`$(document).ready(function(
{`

Try

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.one').mouseenter(function() {
                $(this).fadeOut('slow');
            });

            $('.one').mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).fadeIn('fast');

            });

        });
    </script>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/24/)**</kbd>